# Populating form ListBox from 2D array doesn't work correctly if array has 1 entry

Tags: excel, vba

**ISSUE**

When I try to populate form ListBox using 2D array with only 1 'row', it instead creates separate entries from array column values.

Code is:

```
ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose([DataA]))
```

**WHAT I KNOW**

In my project, data is first gathered into an array from different sources and then added to the listbox.

There are numerous columns and rows of data, which is why passing an array is a preferable way to adding each entry to individual listbox column. Performance is important, as the list needs to update often and fast.

Currently my workaround is to add 2nd row to the array as needed and then to remove it from the listbox directly.

**WHAT I'D LIKE TO KNOW**

Why does the listbox behave differently when passing 1-row 2d array?

**EXAMPLES**

[Example workbook for download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YiAq6Klw2TJbVtfaAXyHrtCEzrgDxFSR/view?usp=sharing)

Populating with 5 rows:

[image]

Populating with 1 row:

[image]

How the data for 5 and 1 row looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could check before if it has one row and then act accordingly:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Dim x
    ListBox1.Clear
    x = [DataB]
    ListBox1.List = IIf(UBound(x, 1) = 1, x, Application.Transpose(x))
    TextBox1 = ListBox1.ListCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @EvR, that's interesting and better than my workaround.